# async Task method that controls the scheduler it runs on

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await

The typical way of writing an `async` Task method is as follows:

```
public async Task<int> LongCalculationAsync(int arg) 
{
     int res = doSomeLongCalculation();
     res += await CallSomeOtherTaskAsync();
     res ++;
     return res;
}
```

When written like this, the first part (before the await) is performed synchronously, and then another Task is created and started on perhaps another thread, which is then continued by a task that contains the last 2 lines and is run on the original context.

The problem is that the synchronous part is performed on whichever scheduler the caller runs on. But my problem is that I know that I want the task returned to run using a specific scheduler, even if the method is called from the UI thread.

Is there a way for the async method itself to decide on the context?

Comment: Have you considered modifying the called function to return a lambda (`Action` or `Func`), and let the caller decide how to wrap it into a `Task` and choose its starting conditions? It may be non-idiomatic but it will give you full control, I guess.

Comment: Another suggestion is to use `Task.Run` inside the callee. [Link to article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Comment: @rwong, Thanks. That would solve the problem of running the task on the thread pull, but what if I wanted to use a specific TaskScheduler? Task.Run does not take a scheduler as parameter...

Comment: @KobiHari Use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. It accepts a `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: @KobiHari: What's your actual use case? Most of the time, async methods either run on the calling context (which they do by default) or on a thread pool thread (which you can do by calling `Task.Run`). It's *very* rare to need to run code on a task scheduler that isn't either of those cases.

Comment: @StephenCleary I have a WPF application and I am writing a class which exposes its APIs as Task<T> methods. I would like its entire code to run on worker threads. I know that on your blog you recommend to leave the Task.Run to the caller and not the implementation, but in this case, this code is dedicated to run only on the WPF app (it will never be called from any ASP.net controller or anything like that) and I don't want to caller to have to know that they need to always use Task.Run to call it. More over, I intend to use a specific private task scheduler.

Comment: @KobiHari: OK, everything you said made sense until the "specific private task scheduler". I'm not sure why you can't just use `Task.Run`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Any chance we can do a short chat to save some comments?

Comment: OK, but I'm in and out right now. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71196/custom-task-schedulers

Answer (score 1):

Use `Task.Factory.StartNew` to push work to any scheduler you want. For the default thread-pool use `Task.Run`. It's quite easy:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doSomeLongCalculation(), ...)
```